# Who has the power to edit or delete another person's comments, and what justifies the edit or deletion

Tags: discussion, comments

It strikes me as a breach of etiquette to edit or delete another person's comment. Where can I find the guidelines on, or discussions of that topic?

Comment: [Lots of info on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: I am also concerned about the way that questions are closed. It may all be done within the rules but I sense a brusqueness about the way it takes place, and a lack of gentility and humour. Some comments on the part of 'offtopickers' (as I call them) can appear quite childish.

Answer (score 7):

Only moderators and the commenter have the ability to edit or delete comments, and commenters can only edit within a short timeframe. I added the comments tag to this question. You can find posts related to these activities within that tag. Please feel free to post another Meta question if you have something more specific that you can't find an answer for.

Comment: What can be "more specific" than asking who has the authority to edit or delete a person's comment?

Comment: Not true. Community members can nuke comments. Posted the correct details.