# You gotta tell me, what's "balled" got to do with it?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, down-votes

One downvote... fine. Normal stuff. Two... again normal (for me it is). But three downvotes for this question?

[The balled (headed) eagle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405245/the-balled-headed-eagle)

Is it because of the title? That's the only fathomable reason I can think of. You can't tell me the question is a duplicate, that there is no research, (but apparently someone disagrees) that it isn't about the English language, or that it's opinion-based. So what is it?

What can I do to improve the question? A user posted the following comment

> And what is the etymology of "bald"??

And someone has cast their vote to close the question because I didn't “include the research”.

Research
There is a link to etymonline, I summarized the information it contained in the body. I cited *Merriam-Webster*, *Oxford Dictionaries*, and  *A Middle English Dictionary*. The question is a result of fact-checking and cross-checking several sources, I carefully avoided copy and pasting a large number of excerpts but... three users think it's not enough.

I now await for the provincial rainfall of DVs on the main page, because I have brought up annoying anonymous downvoting on meta. I know, I'm sick to death of hearing it too, but it's been a long dry summer and I need to quench my thirst.

NB: Users with 1K can [view count votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) If you have less, you have to trust me when I say the question has three downvotes.

On the other hand, the 7 DVs for the *[defeat Trump badly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333038/defeat-trump-badly)* question posted I have no qualms with. It's not my best question by far but at least I know "why" it got downvoted so badly... ho, ho, ho.

Comment: "thirst for knowledge" you understand....

Comment: Brace yourself. Downvotes by [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235226/309993) incoming. ;)

Comment: @NVZ  We'll see. When some people exclaim amazement that I am reluctant to post answers and questions because of anonymous  DVs perhaps they start taking me more seriously. The VTC because it is off-topic takes the biscuit though.

Comment: I don't think there's a good answer (to this meta-question). Especially since there are currently an overwhelming # of upvotes. Three weirdos.

Comment: But, whatever the content, +1 on both titles.

Comment: @Mitch three weirdos, your description not mine, but why do I attract them? Because it is nearly. every. single. time.

Comment: In the US, it's "takes the cake".

Comment: [John Lydgate](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/699462-you-can-please-some-of-the-people-all-of-the) (1370 - 1451) explained your downvotes.  Abraham Lincoln gave a [fuller explanation](http://www.azquotes.com/quote/415900).

Comment: The question has 26 upvotes as of now, why 3 downvotes matter so much? As for the CV, that's just rubbish.

Comment: Did it get those many upvotes by HNQ effect? If not, I think it's already a great question. Forget the 3 downvotes. You can't have everything. :)

Comment: Minor nitpick on your N.B.: Don't you only need to have ["Established User"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privileges to view up/downvote counts?

Comment: @Mari-LouA See [this comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10685/you-gotta-tell-me-whats-balled-got-to-do-with-it/10687#comment44058_10687) under NVZ's answer, please. You get downvotes every single time because *you know how to ask good questions which attract attention*. The better your questions, the more attention they attract, the more upvotes they get receive *along with the absolutely inevitable concomitant downvotes*. You should *not* be surprised when you ask a good question which attracts a lot of upvotes also attracts downvotes. You should *expect* it.

Comment: @Josh because it didn't have 28 upvotes when it received the 3 downvotes, and a VTC for lack of research or for it being better suited to ELL. If there is something wrong, which 3 DVs seem to suggest, I like to know what it is.

Comment: @Hellion I got the 10K mixed up with being able to view deleted posts. You're right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - why do you expect anonymous downvoters to come out? They know you are oversensitive on this issue and get very annoyed about it. They got what they wanted.

Comment: @Josh if I was overly sensitive I would have written dozens of posts. I got three DVs, do you understand? 1 DV is the norm, as is 2 but 3 says something is up (something is not right). UNLESS one of those users also has a sockpuppet, which is very possible. Please note I didn't say anything about the "defeat Trump badly" question, which got 7 DVS. I had enough feedback in the comments (shifted over to chat) that told me why it was being downvoted.

Comment: @Josh but that observation from you is a bit like calling the kettle black, maybe you don't post a complaint on meta but you do delete your answers, all it needs is to have two or more negative feedback in the comments and...poof, it's gone. I happen to get a series of downvoters, 9 times out of 10 whenever I have flagged suspicious behaviour, I was right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, but I don't complain about that,  I think it is just part of  the "game" . I do think that, though you may be right, you are oversensitive about this issue, and that may further feed the behavior of anonymous downvoters.

Comment: I have to admit, my feeling is that posting about a few downvotes (esp when you've gotten a lot more upvotes) is like posting about [why a comment was deleted](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10678/58761). Geesh. Or, cheeses and rice. Sometimes it really helps to try to be a good sport and not take it personally. I doubt you get more DV than the average poster.

Comment: I'll give you a real-time example. It just posted [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/406806/55623), and in my own personal opinion, not only is there nothing objectionable about it, not only does it adhere to the standards of the site, not only does it justify itself, but it happens also to be unambiguously *correct*. And yet as soon as it broke the +5 barrier, it attracted 2 downvotes. This is just the reality. You have to just *expect* downvotes from whatever curmudgeons lurk in the depths ELU, just as we see inexplicable upvotes on dead simple no-research questions.

Comment: @DanBron I can say why you got the downvotes, some users object to the use of too many graphics. It's a language site not one about graphic design. See also the comment left by Edwin Ashworth under the OP. In cases like these, whether you agree or disagree, you can guess why the DVs were cast. In my bald eagle question, I am still absolutely bewildered. Well.... apart from sockpuppets and/or newly made enemies.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, maybe that's it. But I always get some. Images or not, references or not, etc. Usually if the post passes a score o 5 or 10 or some other "round number" threshold. I just expect them. (In this case, given someone went and downvoted the *question*, too, I suspect the downvotes mean "this is not the kind of question I want to encourage on the site, and I don't want answers which encourage it either". But, as I say, always get *some* on highly-voted posts, irrespective of any other attribute).

Comment: @DanBron Bingo. You got your explanation. Whilst the user who cast his vote to close my eagle question also DV my "moschito" question. I know why they DVed, and I'm cool with that. I'm actually surprised by the positive reaction of the spelling Q; however, most of the credit goes to the answers. If the answers had been low-quality the question would have sunk without trace.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable for you to be annoyed.  I just saw the DV today within 15 minutes of posting a thoroughly-researched, interesting question.  That is pretty obnoxious.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime ahh you noticed :) But you know what? I can guess what the DV is for EDIT: POB. Let's see how long it takes before someone casts their vote to close it.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime see comment above. Don't say anything on the main page. I'm curious to see if I'm right.

Comment: Mum's the word.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime thank you for posting an answer. It seems the question is safe as houses, once a day or two has passed by I'll set up a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Your question looks okay. Nothing to worry.

Within a day, your "bald eagle" question has been viewed 2000 times, upvoted 27 times, and answered twice. Those answers are also similarly well received. All this without even entering the *Hot Network Questions*.

I find no reason for those downvotes, but 3 people did. 3 people. Just 3. 3. Let that sink in. 3 down compared to 27 up... 3 is nothing. :)

And so is the case with that one close vote.

Also, it's very much possible that somewhere in your four years here, some users were upset by your actions, and they'll forever hold that grudge, and vote down on your stuff. I get that sometimes as well (maybe even on this answer), because I am a murderer of questions and answers, I have closed, flagged, downvoted and deleted thousands of posts. Thousands.

Comment: Well said, well said! I'd also like to remind everyone of [this inescapable fact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdXi3.png). Everyone's **expectation should be, from an objective, empirical basis, to receive downvotes on any given post**, and in fact, the *better* the post, the more popular the post, the *more likely* it is to receive downvotes alongside upvotes. It's just the reality. People should really stop being surprised, puzzled, or frustrated by it.

Comment: How many upvotes were there before I received the VTC, about 11. That's not to say I'm not delighted with the overall response, and the two answers posted are top notch, you won't find anything close on the Internet. They are "special" BUT... whenever a question gets three downvotes and a VTC well, hell yes, anyone would feel annoyed, puzzled, bemused. The VTC was the last straw.  There is a user out there who sustained the question was off-topic. Let that sink in for a moment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have an answer which has about ~800 upvotes ... and like 5 downvotes. The question it's on has hundreds of upvotes  ... and 5 downvotes. And at one point it had 3 closevotes. It's all a distraction. It means nothing. It doesn't bother me, it didn't bother the OP, the whole episode was a resounding success. All the grumps were summarily ignored.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your questions are, to me and many others, very thoughtful and well-researched. If you care about our opinions, please accept that you have more fans than haters. Do not let the snarky comments or votes let you down. :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou Or maybe your close voter wasn't voting on the content at all. Maybe someone just likes annoying you. Maybe they were bored and wanted someone to post on meta to entertain them. Or maybe they messed up and thought they were voting to close a different question. If there is no noise in the data, it is probably completely fabricated ;)